# Not able to mark C: as active?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

In my older [post](https://superuser.com/questions/325230/how-to-fix-this-disk-doesnt-contain-a-windows-xp-compatible-partition), I asked how to assign drive letter through recovery console. And after spend my whole day with Google I got what the problem is.

> (1) WinXP must be installed as your first version of Windows to a
>   partition which is "primary" and not "logical".
>
> (2) If WinXP is going to be your first/main Windows, then the
>   partition must also be marked as "active".
>
> (3) This target "active" primary partition must be located on a hard
>   drive that is marked as "hard drive #1" in your BIOS list of hard
>   drives, and that it is placed properly in your "boot device sequence"
>   list in the BIOS.

I got the problem that my C: is Primary but not set to active and my bootable USB is primary and as well as set active. Here is A screen-shot of that using Easeus Partion manager. Now how can I set the partition active to install XP as my first OS.

[image: easeus]

[image: diskpart]

I tried to set C: as active through EASEUS but there is this option is not enabled. Then I tried using `DISKPART` but nothing take effect. So now my problem is how can I set my partition as active?

Comment: You have a 100MB primary partition before your (also primary) `C` volume. XP doesn’t like that.

Comment: @Synetech inc. I did format that but after taking backup from windows 7 disk its comeback there.....:)

Comment: Do you still have two primary partitions on the same disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here I overcome on this problem after restore from Windows 7 backup I was still not able to install the Xp on my system so I booted from Windows 7 USB and deleted all partition on my system drive and then booted from Windows XP USB and created the partition and get back on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Disk Management?

Right click My Computer > Manage > Storage > Disk Management. Right click the desired partition > Set as Active

P.S: C: partition seems your first disk and it contains a small partition -probably created by Windows 7 installation- and it might prevent XP to boot. At least XP will prevent Win7 to boot.

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work also same as there that "active" is disabled there too.

Comment: It it's disabled , it might be already marked as active?